# how to set in jwplayer the Fullscreen option in flash mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

as i said, I have a simple jwplayer video

```
var video1 = jwplayer('vid1').setup(
    'flashplayer': 'js/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf',
    'id': 'playerVid1',
    'width': VIDPLAYER_CTRL.BIGVIDEO_WIDTH,
    'height': VIDPLAYER_CTRL.BIGVIDEO_HEIGHT,
    'controlbar': 'over',
    'file': VIDPLAYER_MODEL.MAIN_VIDEO['path'],
    'provider': 'http',
    'startparam': 'start'
}).setVolume(VIDPLAYER_CTRL.BIGVIDEO_VOLUME);
```

and i need to put it on a fullscreen mode with a link `<a id="aFullVideo1" href="#">Set fullscreen</a>`
this link is associated to this code

```
$('#aFullVideo1').on("click", function(){
     jwplayer('vid1').setFullscreen(true);
     return false;
});
```

i know the argument has been faced many times.
i know in the **flash** mode this command is not allowed for security reason.
i checked some plugin, like [this one](http://tutorialzine.com/2012/02/enhance-your-website-fullscreen-api/).
i read pretty much everywhere it's not possible.

but the swf object and javascript should be able to communicate, so i ask myself, is really really impossible, or am i losing something and there is a solution?
thanks to everybody!

Comment: This isn't supported, basically due to what you have already found....

Comment: ok @EthanLongTail, your name suggests me you are one of the Jwplayer developer right? so the next question is obviously this. Can I disable **ALL** operations on the video (buttons bar, play and pause on the video surface, and let **ONLY** the full screen button available? or better even **ONLY** the full screen button visible?

Comment: Yes, but only with a custom skin. We have a SDK available here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/

Comment: for the flash mode i need to use a _zip_ file for the jwplayer settings, instead of the _xml_. the zip file what does it contain? only the xml or even the subdir for every managed component?

Comment: The ZIP file also contains all of the skin assets. You don't need to use the zip though, you can use XML, it will work as well, and for HTML5 mode too.

Comment: really? because it doesn't. that's why I asked you. i simply include it with this `'skin': '/video/six/six.xml'` and i just commented the part of a button (to test), i've no inclusion errors (on firebug) but the button i removed is still visible. at first i try with the zip, then i'll let you know. (i even removed the config `'controlbar': 'over' `)

Comment: What I mean is you can package the skin into a zip file, or use the xml. XML is preferred though, as the zip only works in Flash mode.

Comment: i'm testing it, but there's no way to get the expected effect on the jwplayer command bar. i included with the command i told you before, this is the [xml](http://www.alessandrorabitti.eu/video/six/six.xml). is there something wrong? i am deleting just to test the FullScreen button.

Comment: That should work fine, it should indeed remove those icons from the controls. I have done this myself locally. Can I see where you are running this?

Comment: you know, the problem was the fact that in my localhost the xml configuration doesn't work. the same scripts uploaded in my website, they work fine. so i have to understand why in my localhost the xml config has no effects. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I use xampp for localhost testing. I don't see any issues when testing the skins out locally. If you can email me a zip, I can also test it locally - http://www.longtailvideo.com/contact-us

Comment: @EthanLongTail is even possible in the xml to make disappear the PLAY or LOADING icon/button from the central component `<component name="display">` ?

Comment: Np!

Yes, from the display section, just comment out the following:

<!--<element name="playIcon" src="play.png" />
    <element name="playIconOver" src="playOver.png" />
    <element name="replayIcon" src="replay.png" />
    <element name="replayIconOver" src="replayOver.png" />-->

Comment: @EthanLongTail maybe i express mysefl wrong. i already deleted those part, in fact i don't see any buttons. but if i click the video area, the player still pauses and plays the video. i don't want this operations to be executed too.

Comment: Oh, if you actually want to have clicking the display do nothing, you need to have something over the player in your html then (if you are using v6), as it is not possible to disable the click in v6. If you are using jw5, let me know, though, as that implementation is different.

Comment: any news about it @EthanLongTail ? and another question is, i don't understand why if i switch the controlbar parameter in js to 'over' i am able to manage the controlbar margin with the xml skin, if i set it to bottom (because i need it to be always visible) i've 2 problems => 1) margin setted in the skin are not working anymore, it seems is even fixed in an area and i cannot move it / 2) the icon of toolbar is set too in the bottom, and a part of the icon is cut, because it goes a bit out of the player. i'm using jwplayer 5. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what news you want me to provide here?